# How to deal with incomplete definitions of types and forward declarations in interfaces and implementations

Tags: c, struct, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

Ok, let me preface this question.  This question has been asked, but not answered specifically for a case of not making changes to the .h file, so please do not link to a question that has been answered by saying "oh, move it to the .h file".  I am currently in a class where the teacher hands us the .h file and says, make an implementation to this and DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING IN THE .h FILE.  I followed advice to move structs and such to the .h file on my previous project and was hit very hard on my grade because of that

So, with that being said, let me post a bit of code and get to the nitty gritty.

The .h file

```
#ifndef _list_h
#define _list_h

typedef char *ListItemP  //a pointer to an item in the list
typedef struct List *ListP //a pointer to the List struct itself

somefunctions();

#endif
```

The .c file

```
#include "List.h"
struct List
{
    int foo;
    ListItemP bar;
};

ListP newList()
{
    // implementation, I understand and am confident I used malloc 
    // and everything else correctly to make a new struct
}
```

The main.c or tester.c or whatever you'd like to call it file where I test the implementation and interface (.c and .h respectively)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stlib.h>
#include "List.h"

int main()
{
     ListP n1 = newList();
     n1->foo = 5;

     return 0;
}
```

These are the errors I am getting after compiling on my unix (osx) terminal with gcc -O List.c main.c

```
 main.c:16:5: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct List'

 n1->foo = 5;
 ~~^

./List.h:21:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct List'

 typedef struct List *ListP;
           ^
 1 error generated.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, and if you insist on linking me to a previously asked question then please point out where in that question they answered my specific part of the problem. Maybe I missed it, but I feel as if I've checked through these questions pretty thoroughly.  This problem has been plaguing me since the beginning of this course, so a snippet of code could set me straight but man I'd love an explanation so I can finally understand what I'm doing wrong.  Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: You need to have the contents of the list .c file in the main.c file (i.e. use a single source file). If you had the structure declaration in the header file, then you could use a distinct list implementation file.

Comment: You should try to use only the functions and types declared in `list.h`. If you need to test your implementation that accesses the details of the implementation, add the testing code in `list.cc`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the definition of List is only know by the ".c" file then all code that access its members must be there. That's a valid technique in which you force all other source files to deal only with the pointer but not with its members. Therefore your tester code should call a function that is implemented in the ".c" file in order to populate it.

```
void
setFoo(ListP p, int foo);

int main()
{
     ListP n1 = newList();
     setFoo(n1, 5);

     return 0;
}
```

In the ".c" file where 'List' is defined:

```
void
setFoo(ListP p, int foo)
{
    p->foo = foo;
}
```

Anyway, the prototype of 'setFoo' needs to be visible to your tester program. You might want to define it in the header file or just add it to the tester body itself.

Answer (score 0):

To access members fields in a structure, the code needs to know what member fields exists. If the code doesn't have the structure definition, it will not know what member fields are in the structure and the compilation will fail. That's why structures are usually defined in header files.

So the simple solution to your problem is to put the structure `List` in the `list.h` header file. And if you can't modify the header file, you need to create another header file that contains the structure definition and that you include before the `list.h` header file. And if you can't do that, then you need to make your program a single source file. And if you can't even do that then your problem is unsolvable.